# Описание знака "Сторонник"

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация, знаки

Во-первых, не знаю почему знак "Student" переведён как "Сторонник". Возможно, это так и задумано. Но вот описание к этому знаку явно не окончено:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На английском Stackoverflow это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это разные знаки.

[Стронник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6/supporter) - когда ты сам поставил кому-то плюсик.
[Студент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2/student) - когда твой вопрос заработал рейтинг 1+.

Описание не очень красивое, но вполне дописанное.